# My python program freezes when I input a much larger list length

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write a program that guesses automatically a random number that I generate. And then store the number of guesses on a list.

My inputs are : the maximum number that the random number should not exceed; and the size of the list I want to store the number of guesses on after each guess.

### My method to guess the number very quickly is to use half segmentation or dichotomy.

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np

Max_Number = input()
Size_Liste = input()

if Max_Number.isdigit() > 0 and Size_Liste.isdigit() > 0:
    Max_Number = int(Max_Number)
    Size_Liste = int(Size_Liste)
else:
    print("Please Enter A Positif Integer. Goodbye!")
    quit()
   
NG = []  #This list will store the number of guesses to find the random number


while len(NG) != Size_Liste:
    Random_Number = random.randint(0 , Max_Number)
    #print(Random_Number)
    t1 = 0
    t2 = Max_Number
    Num_Guesses = 0
   
    while True:
        Y = int(abs(0.5 * (t2 - t1))) + t1
        Num_Guesses += 1
       
        if Y == Random_Number:
            break
       
        elif Y > Random_Number:
            t2 =  Y
            continue
       
        else:
            t1 = Y
            continue
   
    NG.append(Num_Guesses)
    continue

print(NG)
```

---

The program works fine when I demand 100 round of guesses (Size_List = 100), but it froze each time I demand a higher size.

Thank you

Comment: `input` always returns a string, so `Size_List` and `Max_Number` will both be strings.  They will never compare true to integers.

Comment: `NG` is an undefined variable.  This code won't even run.  Please post your real code.

Comment: I've made a mistake while pasting the program 
Edit : posted the original code

Comment: `isdigit()` returns a boolean. It doesn't make sense to test it with `> 0`.

Comment: The program print the final list when I demand a smaller size list. So I think the appending works

Comment: There's no need for all those `continue` statements. Loops automatically continue unless you stop them. `continue` is only needed if you want to skip the rest of the loop body.

Comment: Try adding `print(Random_Number)`  to the script. I think you'll see why it hangs. It has nothing to do with the length of the list, except that the more numbers you try, the more likely you are to run into the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your binary search doesn't reach up to the max number that could be randomly generated.

If you do this:

```
Random_Number = random.randint(0 , Max_Number - 1)
```

then if `Random_Number` is assigned to `Max_Number - 1`, then this line:

```
Y = int(abs(0.5 * (t2 - t1))) + t1
```

will reach it.

The problem was never to do with the input of `Size_Liste`.

Comment: Or `t2 = Max_Number + 1`